# Hash Sum mismatch when trying to download package

Tags: apt

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/a94eda4aa2d3ef5591bfc752e3446df9449aeaeef37cddda99c5a5089b9fb665 Hash Sum mismatch    Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:489712 [weak]
    - SHA256:a94eda4aa2d3ef5591bfc752e3446df9449aeaeef37cddda99c5a5089b9fb665
    - SHA1:4783af61fdabef822421f227c2a968540608bb34 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:1fe09da1647b451c6e918f78310cca31 [weak]    Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:d4811bef2509943ed331570c5039a8b652d13d67fe1561c52f0f8ebb61e4dae0
    - SHA1:becffd49c534396f23867c6d7659e83784cb70a1 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2a207edc62799b702bf497cc5464177a [weak]
    - Filesize:489712 [weak]    Last modification reported: Tue, 15 Jun 2021 07:37:08 +0000    Release file created at: Tue, 15 Jun 2021 09:11:40 +0000 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a failure of the OS in downloading some part of a package.

Linux downloads a package and its hash to ensure that the download happened correctly.

It downloads them and take the expected hash of your file and compares it with the actual hash output to ensure file downloaded is correct one.

So you can try to run:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt update
```

Now try to download the package you where downloading.

Comment: I do not quite follow how `autoclean` and `autoremove` are useful elements of the solution.

Comment: How is this a "failure of the OS"?

Comment: yup, i doesnt work...it is clearly a useless element to the solution as this is an issue which is related to the downloading  of the packeages, which has nothing to do with autoclean and autoremove, pls provide another solution.

Comment: Ok, I guess their can be an improvement.